# What <!--[if IE 6]> <![endif]--> does in ASP.Net's asp file?

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

I saw a piece of code like this:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        //$find('mpeIeWarning').show();
        document.getElementById('divIE6').style.display = "";

    }
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Is

```
<!--[if IE 6]> 

<![endif]-->
```

a comment tag? or doing something special, to be honest, I never used this thing.

Answer (score 1):

It adds the script only if the browswer is in fact Internet Explorer 6. It's is a special type of comment, called conditional comment, you can read about it in here 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx